# Git must be used for Scalable App?

Tags: openshift

I am trying to move an old Wordpress install to Openshift.

So I setup two gears, one running MySQL (Gear #1) and the other is setup to be a scalable PHP5 gear (Gear #2). I have manually restored the database data to Gear #1 and manually restored original Wordpress files in Gear #2 under ~/app-root/runtime/repo. The app is running fine now with everything in place.

However, when I try to raise the max number of scalable PHP5 gears from 1 to 2, the app stopped working and showing only the default gear landing page, just like what an empty gear would show. Setting maximum scalable gears back to 1 then the app would work again.

Is it true that the Wordpress files (or any other PHP or web files under ~/app-root/runtime/repo) must be checked in with Git in Gear #2, in order for scaling up to Gear #3+ to work properly? If so, is there anyway I can check-in the files that I already have in Gear #2 from within itself? If not, how can I check-in the set of files that I already have from the old Wordpress install?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers,
KC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the files on your web gear into git you have two options:
1.) SSH or SFTP into your gear and copy the files to your local workstation, then clone your git repo to your local machine, and copy the files into it, git commit & git push.  Then your files will be deployed properly.

2.) SSH into your gear, initialize a git repo in your app-root/repo folder, and then setup your git repo in that gear (the one openshift created) as a remote and add/commit/push your files, then you can do a clone on your local workstation and a push and everything should deploy correctly.

I spoke with operations about this:
We do an rsync from the app-deployments directory, which are the files that were in git.  So it does seem at this point that git must be used for scaled applications to work correctly.  Please add your use case to http://openshift.com/ideas